# How to get row and column values, of a table, on click by a event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two dynamic tables, one with the results of a sum and on other with the sum value, example: 4 and 2+2.

I have the following code in javascript where I click on the table with sum value, and then click on the respective sum value, and when I click on the right sum value, I want to know the value of the index on the column and row of the cell that was clicked.
I have eventListeners to create the clickable cells, and then compare with the cells of the other table.
Here is the code for the clickable cell of the first table:

```
var handler = function(e){if (choiceFlagElement != null) {
        choiceFlagElement.style.background = 'green';
    }
    
    choiceFlagElement = e.target;
    choiceFlagNumber = parseInt(e.target.innerHTML);
    e.target.style.background = 'green';
}
```

and then I have this part for compare to the above cell:

```
var handler2 = function(e){
    if (choiceFlagElement == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    if (choiceFlagNumber == eval(e.target.innerHTML)) {
        e.target.style.background = 'green';
        e.target.style.visibility= 'hidden';
        choiceFlagElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        pontuacao();
        inicio=Date.now();
        count++;
        choiceFlagNumber.target.innerHTML="-1";
        
    }
}
```

Here is where I create the two table:

```
function criartabela(tamanho){
    var tbl = "<table id=tabela>";
    var tbl2 = "";
    var resultados = new Array();
    var f=0;
    for (var ri = 0; ri < tamanho ; ri++) {
       tbl += "<tr>";
        for (var ci = 0; ci < tamanho; ci++) { 
            contas();
            tbl += "<td class='cel"+tamanho+"' id=x visibility=visible >" + a + "+" + b + "</td>";
            var total = a+b;
            resultados[f]=total;
            f=f+1;
        }
    }
    resultados.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
    for(y=0; y<resultados.length; y++){
        tbl2 += "<div class='resul"+tamanho+"' id=total >"+ resultados[y] + "</div>";
    }  
    tbl += "</tr>";
    tbl += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("tabelap").innerHTML = tbl;
    document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = tbl2;
}
```

Comment: Could you put some kind of example on http://jsfiddle.net/? I think that would make it easier to help you

Comment: This is a game for kids, so I think is a bit heavy to post all the javascript

Comment: @user3006760 when demos are requested, it's on you to scale code down to a simplistic enough level to replicate feature you want to implement, or replicate problem you have...without a lot of irrelevant code. That's just the way it works around here. If you show effort, you get help